# Android GPRS C2DM

Tags: android, android-c2dm

In a particular scenario we are registering a device for C2DM notifcation. It is successfully getting the notification when notification triggered from Third party server. Now In case If the GPRS connection for the mobile device gets lossed however it remains connected to operator will it get the push notification.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that the device completely loses data connectivity, then no. C2DM requires data to work.